# Can we assign Autonomous System Number in other way than BGP?

Tags: routing, bgp

Can I assign an Autonomous System Number in other way than BGP?

Comment: FYI you can't assign an ASN anywhere other than in your own lab.  ASNs are assigned by Regional Internet Registries

Comment: This is a common misconception, peoples don't understand ASNs and their relevance for BGP/EIGRP/private ASNs. Perhaps we could make a wiki about it?

Comment: I think this question can be rephrased to: "When and where are ASN's used?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BGP is the only way to use an autonomous system number which is assigned to you.